# WebRtc remote stream

Tags: node.js, react-native, server, webrtc

I have an app (web and react native) that show the user it's local stream and the remote stream. When the 2 are connected, the user on the mobile app sees his local stream and the remote (web) stream. But, the on on the web only sees it's local stream.

The problem is that the stream from the mobile is received and added:[image]

I have a stun server and turn server for udp and tcp setup (tested with trickel-ice). To make it more fun both ways work in local dev. The problem is only on my prod environment.

Web:

```
socket.on("offer", (id, description) => {
  console.log("offer", id, description);
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
  peerConnection
    .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(description))
    .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
    .then((sdp) => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp))
    .then(() => {
      socket.emit("answer", id, peerConnection.localDescription);
    });
  peerConnection.onaddstream = (event) => {
    console.log("onaddstream", event.stream);
    video.srcObject = event.stream;
    console.log("video on add stream", video);
  };
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    event.candidate && socket.emit("candidate", id, event.candidate);
  };
});

socket.on("candidate", (id, candidate) => {
  console.log(candidate);
  peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
});
```

React native:

```
socket
      .on('connect', (_) => {
        console.log('connect');
        //Subscribe to call room
        socket.emit('subscribe', {
          room: urlRoom.replace('/call?room=', ''),
          socketId: socket.id,
        });
        socket.emit('watcher');
      })
      .on('offer', async (id, desc) => {
        console.log('offer');
        peer = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
        peer
          .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc))
          .then((_) => peer.createAnswer())
          .then((sdp) => peer.setLocalDescription(sdp))
          .then((_) => socket.emit('answer', id, peer.localDescription));
        peer.onicecandidate = (e) =>
          e.candidate && socket.emit('candidate', id, e.candidate);
        peer.onaddstream = (e) => {
          console.log('set stream', e.stream);
          e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream && setRemoteStream(e.stream);
        };
      })
      .on('candidate', (id, candidate) =>
        peer.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)),
      )
```

I have a feeling that something is blocking the stream to display.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please post the server side code, so that it will be usefull

Answer (score 0):

you need to create offers both ways. You probably only send offer from web to mobile, that's why you can see both streams on mobile

This is a great article explaining this in details

https://www.pkc.io/blog/untangling-the-webrtc-flow/

Comment: Hi! I checked to be sure but the offer is created both side. Even on my prod env it's working and the streams are shared as long as the web and mobile devices are on the same wifi. The problem occurs when the mobile and web devices are not on the same wifi (ex: the mobile is on a 4g network).

Comment: @VaiteaDoppia Did you find any workaround? I am facing the same problem.